# class instance to all ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, instance

I wish to avoid writing `let APIHelper = API()` in every `UIViewController`, instead I did this:

```
extension UIViewController {
  func APIHelper() -> API {
    let api = API()
    return api
  }
}
```

and now it is working like `self.APIHelper().callMethod()`, but I'm not really sure if it is the way to do it. Any tips on best practice?

Comment: How about some kind of base view controller where you can extend with that declaration? This way ALL of your view controllers have that function, even when you don't need it.

Comment: like class APIViewController: UIViewController { let APIHelper = API() }

Comment: yeah, something like that. and when you need it somewhere you just inherit that view controller.

Comment: I posted an answer with some more info, take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extension useless, since it just same as calling `API()` *everytime*:

```
self.APIHelper().callMethod()
self.APIHelper().callSecondMethod() //here you created another API instance
```

same as

```
API().callMethod()
API().callSecondMethod()
```

If `API` is singletone, idea looks ok, but in swift you usually create singletone with static constant:

```
class API {
    static let sharedAPI = API()
    //...
}
```

and access to it like this:

```
API.sharedAPI.callMethod()
API.sharedAPI.callSecondMethod() //now called in same API instance
```

---

If you don't want to write `API.sharedAPI` everytime, then you can use:

**Your extension**

```
extension UIViewController {
    var apiHelper: API {return API.sharedAPI}
}
```

Not recommended as @NickCatib explained.

**Base view controller**

as @NickCatib suggested (easier with variable):

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    // some of the code you might need
    let apiHelper = API.sharedAPI
}
```

**Protocol**

If you use API in view controllers time to time, can be better declare protocol

```
protocol APIHelper {
    var apiHelper: API {get}
}
```

with default implementation

```
extension APIHelper {
    var apiHelper: API {return API.sharedAPI}
}
```

and connect it to your viewController only when needed

```
class ViewControllerThatNeedsAPI: UIViewController, APIHelper {
    // apiHelper avalible here
}
```

With all three ways you access your API like this:

```
apiHelper.callMethod()
```

Comment: Just a quick note - Singleton does make sence in case you have variable(s) that will eventually change, otherwise it is overkill - it should be static class.

Comment: @NickCatib "static class" - you mean class, that can't have instance? Do you know any implementations it in swift? Or, if you mean "static- like class", class with no any stored properties, so all instances is equal in fact, - then OP can use just `API()` everywhere, but I think that singletone better then many equal instances.

Comment: static class is class where all her attributes and methods are static - so you have base url set once and that's it, and you don't need to store anything else that is dynamic. It would actually go something like this: Service.API().

Answer (score 1):

How about some kind of base view controller where you can extend with that declaration? This way ALL of your view controllers have that function, even when you don't need it.

This would go like

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    // some of the code you might need
    func APIHelper() -> API {
    let api = API()
    return api
  }
}
```

And later:

```
class ViewControllerThatNeedsAPI : BaseViewController {
    // You have it here
}
```

Another approach that I actually use is to have service/manager for API calls that handles that, and send all the data needed via delegate/NSNotification/completion handler. That way your code will be cleaner and easier to test ( if you practice tests ). If you keep everything in the view controller you will break the SRP. This managers are PONSO - Plain old ns objects. You could use the same way as for view controllers and have some BaseService with API URL, basic stuff that needs to be overriden etc. After that you just implement service and call it when needed - depending on the implementation have some function to reflect data to UI.